# How to combine two entities in one view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, view, viewmodel

I need to display the records of the student which is the Student Attempts. 
It should look something like this.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pmazbug2j8xwehe/Example.PNG (Click for image)

But this is the Question page which shows all the correct answers. For the Student Attempts page should be exactly like that only the answers/options are replaced by the answers they attempted so when it is correct, the word will be in green and the wrong ones will be in red.

For this to happen I have to retrieve 2 data from two different entities.

Below is the IQuestion table and QuestionContent is the attribute that holds the model answers and the StudentAttempts table and Answer is the attribute that holds the answers attempted by the students.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/f92f8zvk9qn1n8p/DB%20Tables.PNG (Click for image)

How do I combine those two attributes to display in a view?

StudentAttemptsController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using iStellarMobile.Models;

namespace iStellarMobile.Controllers
{
    public class StudentAttemptsController : Controller
    {
        private istellarEntities db = new istellarEntities();

        //
        // GET: /StudentAttempts/

        public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            var studentattempts = db.StudentAttempts.Include(s => s.activity).Include(s => s.task).Include(s => s.UserInfo).Where(s => s.StudentID == id);
            return View(studentattempts.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /StudentAttempts/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            StudentAttempt studentattempt = db.StudentAttempts.Find(id);
            if (studentattempt == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(studentattempt);
        }

        //
        // GET: /StudentAttempts/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.ActivityID = new SelectList(db.activities, "ActivityID", "ActivityName");
            ViewBag.TaskID = new SelectList(db.tasks, "TaskID", "TaskName");
            ViewBag.StudentID = new SelectList(db.UserInfoes, "ID", "UserName");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /StudentAttempts/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(StudentAttempt studentattempt)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.StudentAttempts.Add(studentattempt);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.ActivityID = new SelectList(db.activities, "ActivityID", "ActivityName", studentattempt.ActivityID);
            ViewBag.TaskID = new SelectList(db.tasks, "TaskID", "TaskName", studentattempt.TaskID);
            ViewBag.StudentID = new SelectList(db.UserInfoes, "ID", "UserName", studentattempt.StudentID);
            return View(studentattempt);
        }

        //
        // GET: /StudentAttempts/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            StudentAttempt studentattempt = db.StudentAttempts.Find(id);
            if (studentattempt == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.ActivityID = new SelectList(db.activities, "ActivityID", "ActivityName", studentattempt.ActivityID);
            ViewBag.TaskID = new SelectList(db.tasks, "TaskID", "TaskName", studentattempt.TaskID);
            ViewBag.StudentID = new SelectList(db.UserInfoes, "ID", "UserName", studentattempt.StudentID);
            return View(studentattempt);
        }

        //
        // POST: /StudentAttempts/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(StudentAttempt studentattempt)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(studentattempt).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.ActivityID = new SelectList(db.activities, "ActivityID", "ActivityName", studentattempt.ActivityID);
            ViewBag.TaskID = new SelectList(db.tasks, "TaskID", "TaskName", studentattempt.TaskID);
            ViewBag.StudentID = new SelectList(db.UserInfoes, "ID", "UserName", studentattempt.StudentID);
            return View(studentattempt);
        }

        //
        // GET: /StudentAttempts/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
        {
            StudentAttempt studentattempt = db.StudentAttempts.Find(id);
            if (studentattempt == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(studentattempt);
        }

        //
        // POST: /StudentAttempts/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            StudentAttempt studentattempt = db.StudentAttempts.Find(id);
            db.StudentAttempts.Remove(studentattempt);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

IQuestion.cs (Models)

```
namespace iStellarMobile.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class IQuestion
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ActivityID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TaskID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CategoriesID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Sentence { get; set; }
        public string QuestionContent { get; set; }
        public string ImageURL { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public string UpdateBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdateOn { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SchoolID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DLevel { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TagID { get; set; }

        public virtual ActivityTask ActivityTask { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual School School { get; set; }
        public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
    }
}
```

StudentAttempts.cs (Models)

```
namespace iStellarMobile.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class StudentAttempt
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ActivityID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TaskID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> StudentID { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
        public string Score { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Attempts { get; set; }
        public string AttemptDate { get; set; }
        public string CorrectAnswer { get; set; }

        public virtual activity activity { get; set; }
        public virtual task task { get; set; }
        public virtual UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Details.cshtml (StudentAttempts view)

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Classes</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
            <h2>   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.activity.ActivityName)    </h2>
        </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.activity.ActivityName)
    </div>
    <br />
   <div class="editor-label">
            <h2>   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.task.TaskName)    </h2>
        </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.task.TaskName)
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="editor-label">
            <h2>   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserInfo.UserName)    </h2>
        </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserInfo.UserName)
    </div>
    <br />
   <div class="editor-label">
            <h2>   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Answer)    </h2>
        </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Answer)
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="editor-label">
            <h2>   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Score)    </h2>
        </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Score)
    </div>
    <br />
   <div class="editor-label">
            <h2>   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Attempts)    </h2>
        </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Attempts)
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="editor-label">
            <h2>   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AttemptDate)    </h2>
        </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AttemptDate)
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="editor-label">
            <h2>   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CorrectAnswer)    </h2>
        </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CorrectAnswer)
    </div>
</fieldset>
<br />
<p>   
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "/Edit/2",null, new { id=Model.ID, @class="classname" }) 
    <span>  </span>
  @Html.ActionLink("Back", "/Index", null, new { @class="classname" })
</p>
```

Comment: Show your code please..

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a new class type (something like "StudentAttempsVM") that has a property for each of the classes you need (Details and Attempts).  Then consolidate your Controller methods to build this object and pass it to your view.

Comment: can give me some examples?